# Sieve of Eratosthenes x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am new to assembly, trying to implement Sieve of Erathothenes, I have the code but it only works between 1 and 600, for some reason it goes haywire when I put n=1000, here is the complete code, any help will do.

```
Include Irvine32.inc
n=1000

.data
prime DWORD n DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
        mov ecx,n       ;initialize ecx to 1000
        mov esi, OFFSET prime
;--------------------------------------------------------
;   Initialize Array with 1's
;--------------------------------------------------------
FillArray:  mov eax,1
        mov [esi],eax
        mov eax,[esi]
        add esi,TYPE DWORD              ;4 to jump to the next index
        loop FillArray

    mov ebx,8
    mov edx,0
    mov ecx,n
    mov ebp,2
    mov esi,0
;----------------------------------------------------------------
;   Sieve
;----------------------------------------------------------------
SIEVE:      mov eax,prime[ebx]
        mov edx,ebx
        mov edi,ebx
        add edx,edi                 ;j=i+i
        mov esi,ebp
        mov ecx,n
        sub ecx,ebp
        add ecx,2
        add ebx,TYPE DWORD
        cmp eax,1
        je FLIP
        inc ebp
        loop SIEVE
        jmp K

FLIP:       mov eax,0
        mov prime[edx],eax
        add edx,edi
        cmp esi,n
        jg SIEVE
        add esi,ebp
        loop FLIP

K:

    mov esi, OFFSET prime
    mov ecx,n
    sub ecx,2   
    mov ebx,1
    mov edx,8           ;Start checking from index of second element

PRINT:  mov eax,prime[edx]          ;
        add edx,TYPE DWORD
        inc ebx
        cmp eax,1
        jne H
        mov eax,ebx
        call WriteDec
        call Crlf
        loop PRINT
        jmp D
H: loop PRINT
D:
    exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Where do you scale `edx` by 4 to index into a DWORD array?  I don't see that happening.  (Of course, it would be much better to make it a byte array, or even a bitmap, since sieve performance is often limited by cache misses on the data.  Reducing the cache footprint by a factor of 4 is a huge win.)

Comment: @PeterCordes `edx` is scaled by adding `edi`, which is `ebx`, which is premultiplied offset. (at least I think so, the logic of this code is so wastefully complex, that it's not easy to follow it in head).

Comment: Well, I tried to figure it out, but it's total minefield, impossible to "run" it in head, so many obscure wasteful complexities making it way too different from short implementation my head expects.

Comment: @Ped7g: That's what I decided after starting to try, which is why I asked for clarification / comments :P  I meant it literally when I said "I don't see it", and didn't mean to imply I was confident that it wasn't happening.  I only weakly suspected.  Anyway, @ OP: use a debugger.  And comment your code much better if you want other people to help you with it.

Comment: Can you be more specific with "it goes haywire"?

Comment: BTW, I'm already too long not using MASM/TASM (to be sure about ".bss" syntax), but the `DB ?`/`DUP (?)` data may be moved to `.bss` segment, to not enlarge the executable size (`.data` is compiled as pre-set binary block and stored into executable in full length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not specific enough with what "going haywire" means, and you probably didn't debug your code, nor you commented it enough to make it easy to follow, so after few minutes looking at it I followed my instinct, which was telling me to start from scratch and write it in regular way.

Whether this will help to you - I have no idea, probably not, at least not without hefty "analyse this" effort.

But I believe this *is* valid answer for a question with title *"Sieve of Eratosthenes x86 Assembly"* and *"any help will do"*.

So here you go, try to understand completely foreign source and try to grasp the ideas used; to a point, where it will start to help you when writing your own code. Good luck. :)

---

First thing ahead of some code, you should clean up your task in terms of math first.

If you would, you would know that there's no point to "sieve" further beyond *sqrt(n)* value.

Because if *sqrt(n)* is prime, then its multiplies 2*sqrt(n), 3*sqrt(n), ..., previous_prime*sqrt(n) are already "sieved" from those smaller prime numbers sieving earlier in the loop.

The first "yet unsieved" number is sqrt(n) * sqrt(n), that's *n* itself, and that's out of array bounds. So after reaching number >= *sqrt(n)* you can end your algorithm main loop (I'm using sharp `number > sqrt(n)` test, because the `sqrt(n)` is truncated to integer, so for special "n" (with integer *sqrt(n)*) I will try to "sieve" *n* itself once, but that will be detected by the test inside `flip_loop` and terminated anyway.

---

```
Include Irvine32.inc
n=1000
n_terminal=31
    ; terminal compare value is min(sqrt(n), 0FFFFh) (last value to process)
    ; no point to sieve beyond sqrt(n), because first unset multiply is
    ; sqrt(n)*sqrt(n) = n => beyond array
    ; and no point to sieve 10000h, because 10000h*10000h is out of 32b

.data
prime BYTE n DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
    ; fill array with "1" (from number 2 to n)
    mov   edi,OFFSET prime+2
    mov   ecx,n-2
    mov   eax,1         ; eax=1 will be used also later (also ah=0)
    rep stosb
    ; set "0" and "1" as non-prime too
    mov   WORD PTR [prime],cx   ; (cx == 0 after "rep stosb")
    ; set "0" to all other non-primes by sieving
    mov   esi,eax       ; esi=1, start the loop as if "1" was handled last
sieve_loop:
    inc   esi           ; next number to test
    ; sqrt(n) is enough to process, beyond that n <= number*number => out of array
    cmp   esi,n_terminal
    ja    sieve_end     ; out of table, end sieving
    cmp   prime[esi],al ; compare with "1"
    jne   sieve_loop    ; not a prime, don't flip the rest of sieve
    ; esi is prime, flip the other multiplies of it, starting from esi*esi (!)
    mov   edi,esi       ; esi*esi as smaller multiples are already covered by
    imul  edi,edi       ; smaller prime numbers sieving the array before
flip_loop:
    cmp   edi,n         ; check if the multiply points beyond table
    jae   sieve_loop    ; if yes, continue main loop with next "prime"
    mov   prime[edi],ah ; set this number to "0" (not prime)
    add   edi,esi       ; edi = next multiply of esi prime
    jmp   flip_loop

sieve_end:
    ; print all primes starting from 2
    mov   esi,eax       ; esi = 1, as if "1" was handled last
print_loop:
    inc   esi           ; while (++number < n)
    cmp   esi,n
    jae   end_print_loop
    cmp   BYTE PTR prime[esi],1 ; eax/al is modified from "WriteDec"
    jne   print_loop    ; not a prime number, loop
    ; esi is prime number, print it
    mov   eax,esi
    call  WriteDec      ; these two calls must preserve esi
    call  Crlf
    jmp   print_loop

end_print_loop:
    exit

main ENDP
END main
```

I did test it under linux with NASM, so I had to change the syntax a bit to compile it, and then change the syntax back for MASM/TASM + irvine, so maybe some tiny bug slipped there during conversion, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked, except " mov   [prime],cx " Should be " mov   [prime],ch" Thanks alot. I was not available to comment on the first one, the prime works right from 1-600 on that one, but when I use 700 and above it prints "random numbers" as I don't understand what's going on with the program, I couldn't debug it because 700 would be so many iterations and I'm new to assembly, you can tell by how that program was poorly written.

Comment: @HughHeimler  **NO** Should be `mov [prime],cx` ... it sets two bytes at the same time, the `prime[0]` and `prime[1]`. If MASM reports some error, enforce that WORD write. Probably `mov WORD PTR [prime],cx` will work in MASM. - which shows you didn't understand even that comment next to it. :/  .... about 700 iterations ... I'm sort of sure some problem would manifest sooner, but in worst case there's probably way to set conditional breakpoint.  | With `mov [prime],ch` the content of memory will show "1" is prime number. Try it in debugger, good opportunity to try out memory view+breakpoints.

Comment: @HughHeimler besides that, as my answer shows, the main loop takes only about ~32 iterations to fill up whole 1000 element sieve. :D ... if your problem is in "flip", then yes, you have over 700 iterations ahead, but you can certainly first verify just the main loop with 31 times hitting breakpoint and checking content of registers + content of "prime" array, to see if flipping went as expected and if next "number" is correctly detected as prime/non-prime. :P

Comment: And about prime[1] being "prime" without that `cx`. It's complicated: you define `prime` in `.data` = it will be zeroed by exe. I set the array to "true" from `OFFSET prime+2`, so to see the bug demonstrated change definition of array to `prime: DB n DUP (0CCh)`. That will show if whole array was initialized correctly ahead of loop (should contain only `0` and `1`). This nicely shows the whole concept of "run it, and check result" is in Assembly useless as a test, passes with luck too often. You really need step over each instruction few times in dbg and reason about it, if it is correct one.

Comment: I will take my time to go through everything, I only started doing Assembly like 3 weeks ago. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @HughHeimler: yep, takes time and practice... as I was doing most of this in my head, you see I had to edit/correct myself several times. But in the end it's deterministic state machine with exactly defined rules, what happens next. It's just question of getting your mind around it in exact way. Plus to have exact idea, what you want to achieve from initial state of machine, what is the requested goal state and which calculations lead to it.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still having problems with this, I have implemented the following code from python to assembly.

```
from math import sqrt

def FindPrimes(limit):
    isPrime = {}

    isPrime[1] = False
    for i in range(2, limit + 1):
        isPrime[i] = True

    checkLimit = int(sqrt(limit)) + 1
    for i in range(2, checkLimit):
        if isPrime[i]:
            for factor in range(2, limit + 1):
                j = i * factor
                if (j > limit): break
                isPrime[j] = False

    primes = []
    for i in range(1, limit + 1):
        if isPrime[i]:
            primes.append(i)

    return primes
```

Please note that the following assembly implementation is in MASM and it requires you to manually input the square root plus 1, since we handle the first DWORD as "isPrime[1]", and of course the limit "FindPrimes(limit)".

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

n=1000
sqrt=32

.data
    sieveArray DWORD n DUP(0)
    primeNumbers DWORD n DUP(0)
    limit DWORD 0
    varInnerLoop DWORD 0                            ;variable j
    falseValue DWORD 0
    primerHelper DWORD 1

.code
 main PROC

    mov ecx,LENGTHOF sieveArray-1
    mov edi,OFFSET sieveArray+TYPE DWORD*2
    mov eax,1

fillUp:
    mov [edi],eax
    add edi,TYPE DWORD
    loop fillUp

checkForPrime:
    mov edi,OFFSET sieveArray+TYPE DWORD*2      ;reset for iteration
    mov esi,[edi]                               ;pointer helper
    mov eax,TYPE DWORD                          ;offset helper
    mov ebx,1                                   ;counter for loopOverNumbers reference
    mov ecx,sqrt-1                              ;sqrt(limit)+1 `limit`¨, -1 because index 0 = index 1, counter
    mov edx,1                                   ;outer loop variable helper for inner loop

    loopOverNumbers:
        cmp ebx,ecx
        je iterateOverPrimes                    ;take me out of the loop because I have iterated over range(1,edx)
        cmp esi,1
        pushad                                  ;save my flags for outer loop, specially ebx and ecx
        je iterateOverFactorsSetUp
        continueIteration:
        popad
        add edi,eax
        mov esi,[edi]
        inc edx
        loop loopOverNumbers

            iterateOverFactorsSetUp:
                mov eax,1                           ;factor for inner loop          
                mov ecx,n+1

                iterateOverFactors:
                    cmp ebx,ecx
                    je continueIteration
                    push edx
                    push eax
                    inc eax                         ;pointer must increment to reflect real value
                    inc edx                         ;pointer must increment to reflect real value
                    imul edx,eax
                    mov varInnerLoop,edx            ;j = i * factor
                    cmp varInnerLoop,n              ;if (j > limit): break
                    jg continueIterationHelper
                    imul edx,TYPE DWORD
                    mov edi,OFFSET sieveArray
                    add edi,edx
                    mov eax,0
                    mov [edi],eax                   ;reset to old value before pointer
                    pop eax
                    pop edx                         
                    inc eax
                    loop iterateOverFactors

            continueIterationHelper:                ;have to pop eax and edx in order to get original values when returning to 
                    pop eax
                    pop edx 
                    jmp continueIteration

iterateOverPrimes:
    mov eax,TYPE DWORD
    mov ecx,n+1                             ;limit helper
    mov ebx,0
    mov edi,OFFSET sieveArray+TYPE DWORD

    checkifPrime:
        mov esi,[edi]
        cmp esi,1
        pushad
        je appendToPrimeArray
        continueSearch:
        popad
        add edi,eax
        inc ebx
        loop checkifPrime
        jmp searchDone

        appendToPrimeArray:
            mov eax,TYPE DWORD
            mov edi,OFFSET primeNumbers
            imul eax,primerHelper                       ;pointer for primeNumbers helper
            add edi,eax
            inc ebx
            mov [edi],ebx
            inc primerHelper
            jmp continueSearch

    searchDone:


INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

In order to check your results, you can check primeNumbers and it will contain every prime number as a DWORD consecutively.

If you have any concerns please let me know :)